# Error establishing connection to CakePHP database

Tags: php, mysql, docker, cakephp, mariadb

I want to learn CakePHP and immidiatly get strange error =) Trying to create a model via the console

```
bin/cake bake model Posts
```

And getting an error

```
root@5b118a83e609:/var/www/public/cake# bin/cake bake model Posts
One moment while associations are detected.
Exception: Connection to Mysql could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
In [/var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php, line 140]

2020-10-07 09:23:42 Error: [Cake\Database\Exception\MissingConnectionException] Connection to Mysql could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php on line 140
Exception Attributes: array (
  'driver' => 'Mysql',
  'reason' => 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory',
)
Stack Trace:
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/Mysql.php:178
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/SchemaDialect.php:47
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/Mysql.php:230
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/Collection.php:53
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php:399
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Utility/TableScanner.php:65
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Command/ModelCommand.php:1060
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Command/ModelCommand.php:191
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Command/ModelCommand.php:122
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Command/ModelCommand.php:98
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Command/ModelCommand.php:81
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/BaseCommand.php:179
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php:336
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php:171
- /var/www/public/cake/bin/cake.php:12

Caused by: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php on line 132
Stack Trace:
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php:132
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Core/Retry/CommandRetry.php:70
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php:138
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/Mysql.php:178
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/SchemaDialect.php:47
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/Mysql.php:230
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/Collection.php:53
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php:399
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Utility/TableScanner.php:65
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Command/ModelCommand.php:1060
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Command/ModelCommand.php:191
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Command/ModelCommand.php:122
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Command/ModelCommand.php:98
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Command/ModelCommand.php:81
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/BaseCommand.php:179
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php:336
- /var/www/public/cake/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php:171
- /var/www/public/cake/bin/cake.php:12
```

Setting are 100% correct: `config/app.php`

```
'host' =>  'mariadb',
'port' =>  3306,
'username' =>  'root',
'password' =>  'password',
'database' =>  'database',
```

I am using Docker. Nearby is Yii2, Laravel, Symfony and WordPress. All works fine and without any errors but CakePHP for some reason cannot connect to the database.

How to fix it?

P.S.:

By the way, if I open a freshly installed framework in a browser, then there will also be an error in the "Database" block

```
CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.
Connection to Mysql could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

At the same time, I tried to connect directly to the database through the native PHP functions `mysql_connect` - everything works! But CakePHP doesn't want to work.

I have already tried changing hosts from `mariadb` to Docker container's `IP` and it didn't help me.

```
'host' =>  '192.168.32.3',
'port' =>  3306,
'username' =>  'root',
'password' =>  'password',
'database' =>  'database',
```

Not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `mariadb` as your host instead of the IP of the actual MySQL container. Normally you can use `localhost` but since you're using Docker this is not possible. Make sure you use the IP of the MySQL/MariaDB container.

In case you don't know how, use `docker ps` and it will show you all your containerID's.
Then look up the IP in the right container (with the containerID) `docker inspect CONTAINERIDGOESHERE | grep "IPAddress"`.

Use this IP in your DB connection instead of localhost and you're set.

So you're config looks like this:

```
'host' =>  '172.19.0.2', // This is example IP, replace it with your found IP
'port' =>  3306,
'username' =>  'root',
'password' =>  'password',
'database' =>  'database',
```

Updated Answer:
Please don't use IP's to connect to containers. IP's can change on container recreation and is therefor a bad practice. Use the container name instead. Just make sure you add the networks line to your container and global. Would look something like this:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    container_name: mariadb
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
    ports:
      - "1027:3306"
    networks:
      - application

  webserver:
    container_name: webserver
    image: nginx:alpine
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
    ports:
      - "1025:80"
    networks:
      - application
networks:
  application:
```

Your DB connection string would look something like this: root:root@containerNameb/dbName

Comment: I have already tryed to change host from mariadb to my IP and it didn't help me.

Comment: mariadb is definitely not correct since that's not a host or hostname, it should be the hardcoded IP of the MySQL Docker container (172.19.0.x).

Comment: That is your host PC's IP, you need to use the IP of your Docker container.

Comment: The command which you write above, give me this container's IP.

Comment: Do you have by any chance a networking mode in your Docker file?

Comment: Yes. I use "networks: - app-network" in my docker-compose.yml

Comment: Try it without, not sure what tue purpose of your app-network setting is.

Comment: Reading this almost 1y later makes me sad as hell. Please don't use IP's when it comes to docker. Use the container name instead since IP's switch on recreation the container.

Comment: I read the answer right away. But forgot to check the box.